# Try to update TYPO3 Core via Composer

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, ddev, composer-php

Working with a local installation (`ddev` & `TYPO3 9.5 LTS`).
Try to update the TYPO3-Core with:

```
composer update typo3/cms-* --with-all-dependencies
```

But `Nothing to install or update`.

```
Package mso/idna-convert is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use algo26-matthias/idna-convert instead.
```

Try to install `composer require algo26-matthias/idna-convert` but it won't help. What's going on? It's still my first steps with composer & TYPO3. How can I update my TYPO3-Package from `9.5.5`to `9.5.8`?

I also try to remove `mso/idna-convert` with

```
composer remove mso/idna-convert
mso/idna-convert is not required in your composer.json and has not been removed
```

Here's my `composer.json`:

```
{
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "path",
      "url": "packages/*"
    },
    {
      "type": "composer",
      "url": "https://composer.typo3.org/"
    }
  ],
  "name": "typo3/cms-base-distribution",
  "description" : "TYPO3 CMS Base Distribution",
  "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
  "config": {
    "platform": {
      "php": "7.2"
    }
  },
  "require": {
    "typo3/minimal": "^9.5",
    "typo3/cms-about": "^9.5",
    "typo3/cms-adminpanel": "^9.5",
    "typo3/cms-belog": "^9.5",
    "typo3/cms-beuser": "^9.5",
    "typo3/cms-felogin": "^9.5",
    "typo3/cms-fluid-styled-content": "^9.5",
    "typo3/cms-form": "^9.5",
    "typo3/cms-impexp": "^9.5",
    "typo3/cms-info": "^9.5",
    "typo3/cms-redirects": "^9.5",
    "typo3/cms-reports": "^9.5",
    "typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor": "^9.5",
    "typo3/cms-setup": "^9.5",
    "typo3/cms-seo": "^9.5",
    "typo3/cms-sys-note": "^9.5",
    "typo3/cms-t3editor": "^9.5",
    "typo3/cms-tstemplate": "^9.5",
    "typo3/cms-viewpage": "^9.5",
    "typo3/cms-filemetadata": "^9.5",
    "gridelementsteam/gridelements": "^9.0",
    "mask/mask": "^4.1.0",
    "georgringer/news": "^7.0",
    "ichhabrecht/content-defender": "^3.0",
    "fluidtypo3/vhs": "^5.1",
    "schmitzal/tinyimg": "^1.3",
    "friendsoftypo3/tt-address": "^4.2",
    "in2code/femanager": "^5.0",
    "typo3/cms-recycler": "^9.5",
    "algo26-matthias/idna-convert": "^3.0"
  },
  "extra": {
    "typo3/cms": {
      "cms-package-dir": "{$vendor-dir}/typo3/cms",
      "web-dir": "public"
    }
  }
}
```

What is it all about this mso/idnaconvert - stuff? How can I fix my composer -installation?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What's your current TYPO3 version? What is the output you get for `composer why-not typo3/cms-core:9.5.n` (`n` being the latest release)?

Comment: Maybe this works: `composer update --with-dependencies $(composer show | grep -oE "^typo3/cms-[a-z0-9-]+")`

Comment: Another thing: do you execute the update command on your local machine or with `ddev composer` or after switching into the web container with `ddev ssh`?

Comment: Your command is completely right. Weird that it doesn' find anything. I have issues with zsh and this command. I escape the star `composer update typo3/cms-\* --with-all-dependencies`. Maybe it's this?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your comments. I will try it out in the evening (I'm not in front of my pc now). My current TYPO3-Version is 9.5.5. I have install TYPO3 with composer and ddev. I'm starting always with `ddev start` and try to handle the composer file.

Comment: As @PeterKraume suggested, I really recommend for consistency that you use `ddev composer` instead of doing it on your host computer. But I would have run `ddev composer update --with-dependencies`

Note that with your existing command line, `typo3/cms-*` will expand in bash to be anything with that path, which won't be valid. If you need that, then you'll want to put it in quotes. That may very well be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this subject is still relevant.
But if you use ddev, you can run `composer update typo3/cms-* --with-all-dependencies` via SSH in the container.
This should work.